# Interop dll referencing other dll

Tags: dll, sdk, interop, iis-7.5

I am using bPAC SDK provided by Brother for their label printer. I downloaded their SDK, took a bpac.dll file and put it inside my projects folder then referenced it. Everything works fine until I deploy my app to IIS server because, as it turns out, that bpac.dll is referencing another .dll in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Brother` folder and IIS does not have required permissions to access that file. This is VERY strange, and strange is that the bpac.dll in my Visual Studio is marked as Interop, whatever it means. How to solve this? How impot all the .dlls to my project so it doesn't need to access files in system folders?

Comment: Have you tried run-time dynamic linking?

Comment: No. What is that and how can it help me?

Comment: It allows you to load the libraries where you want, when you want, and in the order you want. It help you avoid the permission issue, by letting you load local dlls.

Comment: Hi did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: I believe no. I think I just gave IIS permissions to access that .dll.